# Gerrit change is 'Ready to Submit' but Submit is grey, 'Clicking the button would fail'

Tags: gerrit

What am I missing, what do I need to do in order to be able to submit this change? When I hover on the Submit button it says "Clicking the button would fail" (accurate).

[image: Screenshot of gerrit UI]

The relevant change history is:

1. S- uploaded patchset 1
2. S- uploaded patchset 2
3. S- uploaded patchset 4 (dunno what happened to 3?!)
4. C- rebased patchset 4 to be patchset 5
5. C- uploaded patchset 6
6. B- (me) rebased patchset 6 to b patchset 7
7. Patchset 7 received Code-Review+2 and Verified+1.

Using Gerrit 2.12.2.

Comment: There's probably a merge conflict?

Comment: Nope, no new changes have been merged since I did the last rebase.

Answer (score 3):

We had this issue in the past... it was a Gerrit bug. The change owner was removed from the LDAP directory.

See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=4245).

Comment: Mmm...that didn't happen in this case, however the change owner was removed from a Gerrit permissions group. Even adding them back didn't help though. Maybe it's a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove him as reviewer and cast the votes again.